# What's the complexity of running an algorithm that searches over all cuts on a network and returns the minimum?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, network-flow

It's a question of a problem set. If I search for all possible cuts on a network graph and return the minimum, (so it will be equal to max flow), what will be the complexity of running this?

Comment: And I have to explain why and calculate the complexity

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Well, I have drawn a simple graph to see all the posibilities I have to make a cut. I understand the concepts of max flow min cut theorem, but I need some help on found a bound of aplying an algorithm like that.

Comment: I found an answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526905/how-many-cuts-does-a-flow-network-have/1531613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CLRS (3rd, Section 26.2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), the definition of *cut* is rather loose:

> A ***cut*** $(S, T)$ of flow network $G = (V, E)$ is a partition of $V$ into $S$ and $T = V - S$ such that $s \in S$ and $t \in T$.

Therefore, there are $2^{n-2}$ cuts of a flow network $G$ with $|V| = n$, no matter what the underlying graph is.

Obviously, however, not all the possible cuts are interesting (or meaningful) for the network flow problem.

Comment: Thanks!! I understand now, just the combination of s with remaining vertices except t, leads to 2^n-2.